# Summing Detail records in Master Detail SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join

I have two tables

```
Master  
Detail
```

In the Master & Detail table, i have an `Amount` field

I need to get the SUM of Amount in Detail and subtract it from Amount in Master and display in "Current_Amount"

"Current_Amount" should equal to  "Master.Amount" - Sum of "Detail.Amount"

Comment: is there a column which links the two tables?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having a ton of details on the two tables, this will give you the total:

```
SELECT (Max(M.Amount) - SUM(D.Amount)) as CurrentAmount
FROM Master M
INNER JOIN Detail D
    ON M.ID = D.ID
```

Then if you want the Master Id included:

```
SELECT M.ID, (Max(M.Amount) - SUM(D.Amount)) as CurrentAmount
FROM Master M
INNER JOIN Detail D
    ON M.ID = D.ID
GROUP BY M.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select m.ID, max(m.Amount) - sum(d.Ammount) Current_Amount
from Master m
left join Detail D on m.ID = d.Master_ID
group by m.ID
```

- assuming that the Master primary key ID is stored on Detail as Master_ID.

Answer (score 1):

This makes assumptions about the join condition since you didn't specify...

```
SELECT     Master.ID,
           (MAX(Master.Amount) - ISNULL(SUM(Detail.Amount), 0)) AS Current_Amount
FROM       Master
LEFT JOIN  Detail ON Detail.MasterID = Master.ID
GROUP BY   Master.ID
```

**Note:** `MAX(Master.Amount)` simply removes the need to specify `Master.Amount` in the group by clause.